# python Pool result.get() block signal handler

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, signals

I give some long running work to Pool and do result.get():

```
result = my_pool.apply_async(long_run_func)
result.get()
```

The process will be blocked here and I try to send a signal to this process. Then I found the signal handler will only be called after the result.get() finished.

Here is the sample code I ran:

```
import os
import sys 
import atexit
import time
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Pool
from signal import signal,SIGTERM,SIG_IGN


def func_in_pool():
    for i in range(10):
        print 'Sleeping... %d'%i
        time.sleep(1)

def func_in_atexit():
    print 'Calling from atexit()'

def func_in_thread():
    print 'Calling from thread.'
    time.sleep(4)
    print 'Calling from thread: os.kill()'
    os.kill(os.getpid(), SIGTERM)

def init_worker():
    signal(SIGTERM, SIG_IGN)

my_pool=Pool(2, init_worker)
signal(SIGTERM, lambda signum, stack_frame: sys.exit(1))
atexit.register(func_in_atexit)

mythread = Thread(target=func_in_thread)
mythread.start()
print 'Thread has been started'
result = my_pool.apply_async(func_in_pool,[])
result.get()
time.sleep(2)
print 'After get()'
mythread.join()
```

I expected the process will end after 4s but it actually end after 10 seconds, which means result.get() has returned.

The output is like this:

```
python myexit.py
Calling from thread.
Thread has been started
Sleeping... 0
Sleeping... 1
Sleeping... 2
Sleeping... 3
Calling from thread: os.kill()
Sleeping... 4
Sleeping... 5
Sleeping... 6
Sleeping... 7
Sleeping... 8
Sleeping... 9
Calling from atexit()
```

The signal handler there is to make sure the function registered in atexit will get call. How could I let the background thread generate a signal and the signal handler get imidiately called?

(If don't put the signal handler there, the process will end when the signal is generated by the thread. However, in this case, the function registered in atexit will not get called.)

Comment: Not sure if this helps but something I did in a relatively similar situation was use the 'callback' parameter of apply_async to handle the values as they are computed.  Note that the callback function will also block the entire pool if it doesn't execute fast enough, so it helps to hand the data off to another process or otherwise record it so you can retrieve it when desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue8296) in Python.  The workaround is to specify a timeout in `get()`--even a very long one will do:

```
result.get(timeout=525600*60) # It's time now, to sing out
```

Comment: This solution works good. However, the processes inside pool do not stop when the signal handler get called. The terminal will hang up there after the processes inside pool finishing their work... How can I also stop those processes?

Comment: This is why I've basically given up on pools. I've tried both process pools and thread pools, in multiprocessing and concurrent.futures, and they both suffer from this same bug. It's been around for a long time, too, but isn't really documented. Often it's just easier to use lower level constructs and tailor them to what you're actually trying to do. It's a common dilemma in computing, that when you try to simplify things with complicated tools, you often just make things more complicated. You'll get more done with a tool box then with a Swiss army knife:)